# Show that $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i}$ is of degree $2n$, even..., using the binomial coefficients formula

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

In the previous questions i've proved that $(1+i)^{2n+1}=a_n+ib_n$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $\pm 2^n$ and that $(1-i)^{2n+1}=a_n - ib_n$ and that $|P_n(1)|=2^n$ using the previous statements. But now I need to show that the polynomial $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i}$ is of degree $2n$, even (the coefficient in front of $X^n$ is non-zero only when $n$ is even, with real coefficients, and with $2n+1$ as a dominant coefficient, using the binomial coefficient formula.

I also need to show that the coefficient $X^{2n-2}$ in $P_n$  is $\frac{n(1-2n)(1+2n)}{3}$.

I don't really know how to use the binomial coefficient formula to prove those claims, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use
$$ (a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k, i^{2k}=(-1)^k, i^{2k-1}=(-1)^{k+1}i $$
and you will get the answer.